# jQuery each function doesn't work on IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, each

I have this piece of code in Javascript:

```
var len = 0;
$('#list > input').each(function() {
    if($(this).attr('checked')) len++;
});
if(!len) {
    alert("{$err.no_list_chosen}");
    return false;
}
return checkFormAdd();
```

It should iter the list of checkbox to be sure that AT LEAST one is checked, otherwise, return Error.
All this is not working on Internet Explorer 8, and maybe on 7 too.
Can someone help me to rewrite the code so that it could be good for all the browsers?

Comment: You can simplify this: `var len = $('#list > input:checkbox:checked').length` - but it should work in all browsers anyway...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, just use one line:

```
var amountOfChecked = $('#list > input:checked').length;
```

It works in all browsers, just like your code, but this is without the spaghetti...